# How to get all associations for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Is there any way in rails to get a list of all associated models for a given model?

I'm thinking in something like:

```
post_associations = Post.associations()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Post.reflections
#=> { :author => #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x0...>,
      :comments => #<ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection:0x0...> }

Post.reflections.keys
#=> [:author, :comments]
```